# JS function if/else to toggle display not working

Tags: javascript

I want a button that toggles display none and block. It works the first time hiding the H1, but doesn't work the second time. I looked inside the console, and it's only toggling the first if statement.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1 {display: block;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="hello">hello there</h1>
        <button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        var h1 = document.getElementById("hello")

        function hide() {
            if (h1.style.display ="block"){
                h1.style.display ="none"
                console.log ("display none")
            } else if (h1.style.display ="none"){
                h1.style.display ="block"
                console.log ("display block")
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

I have tried

```
if (h1.style.display == "none")
```

but it doesn't work at all then. Doesn't even toggle the first time.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: Because of your code missing on if block if (h1.style.display ="block"){ you shoul use doubke equal ==

Comment: I thought that as well, but having == or === doesn't toggle the display at all

Comment: it doesn't matter you tried == or === , in your code `if (h1.style.display = "block")` is always `true` because it's an expression that returns non zero length string in this case `"block"`. your first `if` block always is `true` by doing this `if (h1.style.display = "block")`

Comment: ANSWER: the reason it doesn't work is because you must initial style.display of `h1` to `block` other wise none of if statements work: add this to your `h1` tag `style="display:block;"` dont forget to replace = to == or ===

Comment: Thank you User 'High' I got it work

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you assign instead of check:

```
if (h1.style.display ="block")
```

One `=` means to assign 'block' to the display property and the it will return true and therefore it always will set the display to false.

you should do this like this:

```
if (h1.style.display == "block")
```

And

```
} else if (h1.style.display == "none"){
```

You also can make your code more efficient by using some ES6 features:

```
h1.style.display = h1.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block'
```

The `?` mark is a short if and the `:` is the short else.

So it basically says if the value is block, set it to none, else, set it to block.

Read more about Operators in JS and ES6.

Comment: I tried this at first, but then it wouldn't toggle the display at all

Answer (score 0):

toggle can be directly assumed on class assignation

see doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

sample code:

```js
const myHello      = document.getElementById('hello')
  ,   mybtShowHide = document.getElementById('bt-show-hide')


mybtShowHide.onclick =() =>
  {
  let status = myHello.classList.toggle('noDisplay')

  console.clear()  
  if (status) console.log ("display none")
  else       console.log ("display block")
  }
```

```css
.noDisplay { display: none; }
```

```html
<h1 id="hello">hello there</h1>
<button id="bt-show-hide"> show / hide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`h1.style` refers to the style attribute on the HTML tag. For more control, I would recommend using `classList` to determine if a `hide` class is on the element. I tested the following code and it works.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .hide {display: none;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="hello">hello there</h1>
        <button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        var h1 = document.getElementById("hello")

        function hide() {
            if (h1.classList.contains('hide')) {
                h1.classList.remove('hide');
            } else {
                h1.classList.add('hide');
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using assignment `=` in the `if` and `else if` conditions. You should use `==` or `===` to check for equality. Also you don't account for the initial case where `element.style.display` be empty e.g. `""`

But the real answer is: don't do this. Use a MVC, MVVM, MV* framework such as React, Angular, etc to hide/show things for you based on some model. These can handle much more complicated model and transform the UI in many other ways for you.

Comment: lol I'm just starting out with javascript and messing around for now. I'll get to react eventually

Comment: Alright, it is very good you have that on your mind. I think it is even better you make sure you know how the plain HTML/JavaScript work also before (or while) using those frameworks. Enjoy learning JS!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer that I found was this:

it doesn't matter you tried == or === , in your code if (h1.style.display = "block") is always true because it's an expression that returns non zero length string in this case "block". your first if block always is true by doing this if (h1.style.display = "block")

ANSWER: the reason it doesn't work is because you must initial style.display of h1 to block other wise none of if statements work: add this to your h1 tag style="display:block;" dont forget to replace = to == or === –

And so I made the code like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1 {}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="hello">hello there</h1>
        <button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        var h1 = document.getElementById("hello")

        h1.style.display = "block"

        function hide() {
            if (h1.style.display == "block"){
                h1.style.display = "none"
                console.log ("display none")
            } else if (h1.style.display == "none"){
                h1.style.display = "block"
                console.log ("display block")
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Not the cleanest, but it works

Comment: The assignment "expression" returns the value that has been assigned to the left side. E.g. `if(myVar = 0) { console.log('it will not work'); }` will not execute the `if`

Comment: Even if you want to assign and check for the value at the same time, do not do this because it makes the code less readable. Instead do the assignment and the check the variable in the if

Answer (score 0):

There is two things missing in above code .

1. To use equality operator than assignment operator for comparison:
   h1.style.display === "block"
2. a) To get actual element styling need to use DOM CSS .
   b) To access style property from DOM need to use inline styling .

Method a:
using DOM CSS:

```js
var h1 = document.getElementById("hello");
       
        function hide() {
        
        var h1Display = window.getComputedStyle(h1).display;
            if (h1Display === "block"){
                h1.style.display ="none";
            } else if (h1Display === "none"){
                h1.style.display ="block"
            }
        }
```

```css
h1 {display: block;}
```

```html
<html>
        <body>
            <h1 id="hello" >hello there</h1>
            <button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
        </body>
  </html>
```

Method b) using inline styling :

```
<html>
<h1 id="hello" style="display:block" >hello there</h1>
     <script>
            var h1 = document.getElementById("hello");
    
            function hide() {
                if (h1.style.display === "block"){
                    h1.style.display ="none"
                    console.log ("display none")
                } else if (h1.style.display === "none"){
                    h1.style.display ="block"
                    console.log ("display block")
                }
            }
        </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="hello">hello there</h1>
        <button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        var h1 = document.getElementById("hello")

        function hide() {
            if (hello.hidden==true){
                hello.hidden=false;
        
            } 
            else{
                hello.hidden=true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```